# Use Base64OutputStream to Upload String to Server - Android

Tags: android, base64, photo

I have been using this code, but have been running into some memory issues:

```
      // Get the image from the sdcard
      Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/myimage.jpg");
      // turn image into byte array output stream
      ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
      // 'compress' the jpeg
      bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);               
      // get byte[] array of the image        
      byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray();
      // turn image into base64 string        
      String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
      // and base64 string to 'params' value pair        
      params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userfile", encodedImage));

      try {
       HttpPost request = new HttpPost();

       String urlString = "http://www.example.com";
       request.setURI(new URI(urlString));

     if(params != null) {
        request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        client.execute(request);
     } // end if
} // end try
```

It has been suggested that I should use `Base64OutputStream` instead of `Base64.encodeToString` , but I have not been successful in using `Base64OutputStream` outputting a string that I can upload to the server. Any examples of using `Base64OutputStream` on an IMAGE would be a great help.

EDIT

To make the answer work, You need to add two files to your Android project: apache-mime4j-dom-0.7.2.jar and httpmime-4.1.3.jar;

You can download apache-mime4j-dom-0.7.2.jar from http://james.apache.org/download.cgi#Apache_Mime4J - download the binary, unzip it, and find the apache-mime4j-dom-0.7.2.jar file.

Then go to http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/4.1.3 and download httpmime-4.1.3.jar

Then drag both those files into your project in Eclipse. Then in Eclipse, choose Project > Properties. Select the Properties Pop-up, select Java Build Path. Click the "Libraries" tab (Look for Source | Projects | Libraries | Order and Export). Click "Add Jars" and selectapache-mime4j-dom-0.7.2.jar and httpmime-4.1.3.jar; Then click the "Order and Export" tab. Check apache-mime4j-dom-0.7.2.jar and httpmime-4.1.3.jar; Then close that popup and choose Project > Clean from the Eclipse menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, you should not base64encode your files and send them in URL, but use MultiPart file upload instead:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity( HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE );

// picture
entity.addPart( "userfile", new FileBody( 
    new File( MyApp.getContext().getFilesDir(), "userfile.jpg" ),
    "image/jpeg")
);

entity.addPart( "blahblah", new StringBody( "blah" ));  // string value

post.setEntity( entity );
client.execute( post );
```

Comment: Can you tell me where I get the JAR so I can use MultipartEntity? I tried this before and downloaded everything I could find from apache, but nothing seemed to work.

Comment: I edited the original post to show where to get the JAR files and how to add them to your project.

Comment: @Chris: sorry for being late, you've already found the files.